# Import CSV within SQL Server 2008 Management console

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file within the SQL Server Management console.
The CSV is comma delimited.

I have some columns that has a comma within double quotes, it seems that SQL Server splits the value in 2 columns.

How can I solve this?

I hope you can understand what I mean.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have customise the column separators for this column as starts `,"` and ends `",`

You can do this in a dedicated SSIS package (which is what SSMS uses underneath). Similar to format files with bcp/BULK INSERT. I can't check right now sorry if the same option is offered in the SSMS wizard